# How to use in grails the 'classForName' for classes under src/groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

To get a class instance, with a String name, I'm using (in a Controller):

```
grailsApplication.getClassForName('className')
```

If the class is under "grails-app", everything works fine. But the code returns null when the class is under "src/main/groovy"

Does anyone know how I do this in grails (3.1.8)?

Comment: Just use regular reflection API and `Class.forName()`

Answer (score 0):

To get a class (including classes in src/main/groovy), you can use

`grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(classNameWithPackage)`

To get a new instance for this class, you can call the `newInstance()` method on the class.

So, finally, this would solve your problem.

`grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass(classNameWithPackage).newInstance()`

I hope this helps.